# Similar code in seed method, first works, second not. ASP.NET MVC adding role to user. Can anyone help me with this?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I need to add some test records to database.

In first code (works fine) I used random names for user. Function `RandomString()` generates name from string with letters:

```
protected override void Seed(ApplicationDbContext context)
{
    (...)
    for (int i = 0; i <= 1000; i++)
    {
        var s = RandomString(8);
        var n = RandomNumber(43);
        if (!context.Users.Any(u => u.UserName == s))
        {
            var store = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context);
            var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(store);
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = s, Email = s + "@eturniej.pl", EmailConfirmed = true };
            user.UserPhoto = bimages[n];

            manager.Create(user, "!Qazxc");
            manager.AddToRole(user.Id, "User");
        }
    }
}

private static string RandomString(int Size)
{
    Random random = new Random();
    string input = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    var chars = Enumerable.Range(0, Size)
                           .Select(x => input[random.Next(0, input.Length)]);
    return new string(chars.ToArray());
}

private static int RandomNumber(int Size)
{
    Random random = new Random();
    int number = random.Next(Size);
    return number;
}
```

And in second one (not working) I used names from file (every name in different line in file) for user. File contains 643 names.

```
protected override void Seed(ApplicationDbContext context)
{
    (...)
    string[] names = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\mateu\Source\Repos\MateuszGawrysiak\eTournament\eTournament\Content\imiona.txt");
    for (int i = 0; i <= 642; i++)
    {
        var n = RandomNumber(43);
        var _name = names[i];
        if (!context.Users.Any(u => u.UserName == _name))
        {
            var store = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context);
            var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(store);
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = _name, Email = _name + "@eturniej.pl", EmailConfirmed = true };
            user.UserPhoto = bimages[n];

            manager.Create(user, "!Qazxc");
            manager.AddToRole(user.Id, "User");
        }
    }
}

private static int RandomNumber(int Size)
{
    Random random = new Random();
    int number = random.Next(Size);
    return number;
}
```

I checked everything with debbuger and names are loading correctly, names.count is equal 643, when I run this seed method without this line: `manager.AddToRole(user.Id, "User");`
Everything is working.
Error message I am getting:

```
PM> update-database
Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database.
No pending explicit migrations.
Running Seed method.
System.InvalidOperationException: UserId not found.
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager`2.<AddToRoleAsync>d__83.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.AsyncHelper.RunSync[TResult](Func`1 func)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManagerExtensions.AddToRole[TUser,TKey](UserManager`2 manager, TKey userId, String role)
   at eTournament.Migrations.Configuration.Seed(ApplicationDbContext context) in C:\Users\mateu\Source\Repos\MateuszGawrysiak\eTournament\eTournament\Migrations\Configuration.cs:line 206
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrationsConfiguration`1.OnSeed(DbContext context)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.SeedDatabase()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.SeedDatabase()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.UpdateInternal(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.<>c__DisplayClassc.<Update>b__b()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Update(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.UpdateRunner.Run()
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner runner)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Update(String targetMigration, Boolean force)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.UpdateDatabaseCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
UserId not found.
```

Can anyone help me with this? And sorry for my english ;)

Comment: What is this line doing ?    manager.Create(user, "!Qazxc");         Is it creating user in your database? Is it able to create that successfully and populate the User.Id field

Comment: Yes, this line is creating users in my database. When i run this seed method  without this line: manager.AddToRole(user.Id, "User") Users are created but without roles.

Comment: Exception clearly says "System.InvalidOperationException: UserId not found.". That can easily mean that when manager.Create is creating user, it is either not creating Id, or not populating it back to user entity.

Comment: But in first code where only change is that I'm using different string for UserName, everything works fine.

Comment: i think you are missing pranthsis  after "new ApplicationUser". shouldn't this line be like this  "var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = _name, Email = _name + "@eturniej.pl", EmailConfirmed = true };"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution that worked for me:

```
            for (int i = 0; i <= 642; i++)
            {
                var n = RandomNumber(43);
                var _name = names[i];
                if (!context.Users.Any(u => u.UserName == _name))
                {
                    var store = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context);
                    var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(store);
                    var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = _name, Email = _name + "@eturniej.pl", EmailConfirmed = true };
                    user.UserPhoto = bimages[n];

                    manager.Create(user, "!Qazxc");
                    ApplicationUser _user = manager.FindByName(_name);
                    if (_user != null)
                        manager.AddToRole(_user.Id, "User");

                }
            }
```

I still do not know why I had to do that this way.